# How can I pass values from component from A to B component in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jhipster, react-tsx

Parent component

```
export interface IInvoiceDetailProps extends StateProps, DispatchProps, RouteComponentProps<{ id: string }> { }

export const InvoiceDetail = (props: IInvoiceDetailProps) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    props.getEntity(props.match.params.id);
  }, []);

  const { invoiceEntity } = props
  
  return (
    <Row>
      <**InvoiceItem** {...props} />
    </Row>
   );
} 

const mapStateToProps = ({ invoice }: IRootState) => ({
  invoiceEntity: invoice.entity,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = { getEntity };

type StateProps = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps>;
type DispatchProps = typeof mapDispatchToProps;

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(InvoiceDetail);
```

Child Component

```
export interface IInvoiceItemProps extends StateProps, DispatchProps, RouteComponentProps<{ url: string }> {}

export const InvoiceItem = (props: IInvoiceItemProps) => {
  const { invoiceItemList, match, loading } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <h2 id="invoice-item-heading">
        Invoice Items
      </h2>
    </div>
   ) 

}

const mapStateToProps = ({ invoiceItem }: IRootState) => ({
  invoiceItemList: invoiceItem.entities,
  loading: invoiceItem.loading,
  totalItems: invoiceItem.totalItems,
  links: invoiceItem.links,
  entity: invoiceItem.entity,
  updateSuccess: invoiceItem.updateSuccess,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  getEntities,
  reset,
};

type StateProps = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps>;
type DispatchProps = typeof mapDispatchToProps;

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(InvoiceItem);
```

Here, I want to pass few data from InvoiceDetails to InvoiceItems.
How can I pass that and access it in InvoiceDetails ?

As an example, I want to pass InvoiceDetails ID(primary key) in IvoiceItems to fetch data accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Passing data from a child to parent is simple in React. Create a state variable in your parent component:

```js
const [data, setData] = useState({});
```

Then, in your JSX, pass the setData function:

```js
<InvoiceDetails {...props} setData = {setData} />
```

Then in your `InvoiceDetails` component, you can call setData and set it to whatever you want which will update the state variable in the parent as well.

Comment: With that approach getting below error. 
```
Type '{ setData: any; invoiceEntity: Readonly<IInvoice>; history: History<unknown>; location: Location<unknown>; match: match<{ id: string; }>; staticContext?: StaticContext; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { match: any; }'.
  Property 'setData' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { match: any; }'
```

Comment: Can you re check above question?
I want to access InvoiceItem in InvoceDetails. And want to pass few value in InvoiceItem